# What methods and properties do Vala arrays support?

Tags: vala

The [Vala Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Arrays) mentions the following methods and properties (and operators) for built-in arrays:

```
arr.length
arr += element
arr.resize()
arr.move()
```

(By "built-in arrays" I mean ones like `int[] arr = new int[5]`, in contrast to the fancy data structures provided by GLib or Gee.)

**My question**: do such arrays support any more methods and properties? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the compiler source code there should also be `arr.copy()`:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/blob/master/vala/valaarraytype.vala

Also if you look at the unit tests you can see that slices (e.g. `arr[1:5]`) are a feature of arrays:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/blob/master/tests/basic-types/arrays.vala

But I think thats it. The built-in array is pretty minimalistic.

Comment: Thanks. (For completeness sake I'll mention the **in** operator and the **foreach** statement.)